# Hive Error "The second and the third arguments of function IF should have the same type, but they are different: "timestamp" and "string""

Tags: hive

I am getting the following error in Hive:

"The second and the third arguments of function IF should have the same type, but they are different: "timestamp" and "string"

Here is the query:

```html
 
with cte_fix_on_time AS (

SELECT 
 *, 
  SPLIT(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(CAST(timestamp AS STRING),'yyyyMMddHHmmss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),' ')[0] as bl_date,
 SPLIT(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(CAST(timestamp AS STRING),'yyyyMMddHHmmss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),' ')[1] as bl_time
FROM 
 table
)

SELECT 
 *,
 SUM(baseline_visits) OVER(ORDER BY locale, CAST(timestamp AS INT) ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 4 FOLLOWING) as bl_ad_visits,
 IF(CAST(CONCAT(bl_date,' ',bl_time) AS STRING)<'2016-03-08 00:00:00'),to_utc_timestamp(CAST(CONCAT(bl_date,' ',bl_time) AS STRING), 'CET'),CAST(CONCAT(bl_date,' ',bl_time) AS STRING)) as utc_timestamp,
 SPLIT(CAST(IF((CAST(CONCAT(bl_date,' ',bl_time) AS STRING)< '2016-03-08 00:00:00'),to_utc_timestamp(CAST(CONCAT(bl_date,' ',bl_time) AS STRING), 'CET'),CAST(CONCAT(bl_date,' ',bl_time) AS STRING)) as STRING),' ')[0] as utc_date,
 SPLIT(CAST(IF((CAST(CONCAT(bl_date,' ',bl_time) AS STRING)< '2016-03-08 00:00:00'),to_utc_timestamp(CAST(CONCAT(bl_date,' ',bl_time) AS STRING), 'CET'),CAST(CONCAT(bl_date,' ',bl_time) AS STRING)) as STRING),' ')[1] as utc_time
FROM 
 cte_fix_on_time
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: The whole code does not make much sense. Add a data sample including required results.

Answer (score 0):

Your second argument (the "then" part) is a timestamp:

`to_utc_timestamp(CAST(CONCAT(bl_date,' ',bl_time) AS STRING)`.

Your third argument (the "else" part) is a string:

`CAST(CONCAT(bl_date,' ',bl_time) AS STRING)`.

You need to either to  use `to_utc_timestamp` on your third argument or stop using it on your second.